# Detect angle and rotate image using HoughLine Transform

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm trying to rotate an image that is clearly seen with rotation.

I'm using HoughLine with opencv.

Here is the image with code below ([working in google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_ZknesnY9hquEC0A5GI1nngYI6tSYhjz)):

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

image1 = cv2.imread('/content/rotate.png')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

canimg = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)
lines= cv2.HoughLines(canimg, 1, np.pi/180.0, 250, np.array([]))
#lines= cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 80, np.array([]))
for line in lines:
    rho, theta = line[0]
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(image1,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)
print(theta)
print(rho)
cv2_imshow(image1)
cv2_imshow(edges)
```

This is the ouput:

theta: 0.9773844

rho: 311.0

[image]
[image]

So, when I try to rotate this image with this line and then show it:

```
img_rotated = ndimage.rotate(image1, theta)
cv2_imshow(img_rotated)
```

This is the output:

[image]

This result does not agree with the rotation that it should be for the frame to be horizontal.
Any advise? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the documentation on the theta angle. It is the direction perpendicular to the lines. See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ndimage.rotate angle in degrees.

```
img_rotated = ndimage.rotate(image1, 180*theta/3.1415926)
```

Comment: It works, but how It could be to get horizontally instead vertically? This is the result with the line code: https://prnt.sc/sbks0a

Comment: test please:
img_rotated = ndimage.rotate(image1, 180*theta/3.1415926+90)
or
img_rotated = ndimage.rotate(image1, 180*theta/3.1415926-90)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was several time trying to do this.